# How to extract transformation coefficients calculated with GDAL based on GCPs?

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I want to precompute the least squares fit polynomials from a provided set of GCPs, and store the coefficients for later transformation of points between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates. Thus I could transform only a part on an image using precomputed transform. Is it possible to extract the transform calculated with GDAL based on GCPs?

I know it's possible to transform only a part on an image based on a RPC model, by slightly changing the RPC file to correspond to the given part of an image. So I've tried to use Orfeo Toolbox utility GenerateRPCSensorModel to convert GCPs into RPC model, but the results weren't good...

EDIT
I'm writing code in Python

Comment: Have you checked what GDALCreateGCPTransformer does? http://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#ac57c80f7bf6752fac1dff8c2a21a15a3

Comment: @user30184, yes, I have seen the GDALCreateGCPTransformer. The problem is that I'm writing in Python and the transformer is in C only... Maybe there is a way to pass the transformation into gdal.Warp() in Python?

Comment: @user30184, I've also seen the autotests  on gdal.Transformer https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/794d31877df592d4fb8ac67a7ad6e151bf015ab9/autotest/gcore/transformer.py. Can I use the Transformer to warp raster data?

Comment: Sorry, I am not so deeply involved.

Answer (score 2):

[ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module can be used to call [GDALCreateGCPTransformer](https://gdal.org/api/gdal_alg.html#_CPPv424GDALCreateGCPTransformeriPK8GDAL_GCPii)(), and then read the coefficients from the result ([GCPTransformInfo](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.2.0/gdal/alg/gdal_crs.cpp#L81) structure). However, keep in mind, that GCPTransformInfo structure is non-public and can be changed in future versions.

Code example:

```py
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.util as ctu


class Gcp(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("pszId", ct.c_char_p),
        ("pszInfo", ct.c_char_p),
        ("dfGCPPixel", ct.c_double),
        ("dfGCPLine", ct.c_double),
        ("dfGCPX", ct.c_double),
        ("dfGCPY", ct.c_double),
        ("dfGCPZ", ct.c_double)
    ]


class GDALTransformerInfo(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("abySignature", ct.c_byte * 4),
        ("pszClassName", ct.c_char_p),
        ("pfnTransform", ct.c_void_p),
        ("pfnCleanup", ct.c_void_p),
        ("pfnSerialize", ct.c_void_p),
        ("pfnCreateSimilar", ct.c_void_p)
    ]


class GCPTransformInfo(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("sTI", GDALTransformerInfo),
        ("adfToGeoX", ct.c_double * 20),
        ("adfToGeoY", ct.c_double * 20),
        ("adfFromGeoX", ct.c_double * 20),
        ("adfFromGeoY", ct.c_double * 20),
        ("x1_mean", ct.c_double),
        ("y1_mean", ct.c_double),
        ("x2_mean", ct.c_double),
        ("y2_mean", ct.c_double),
        ("nOrder", ct.c_int),
        ("bReversed", ct.c_int)
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        s = ct.string_at(self.sTI.pszClassName).decode() + "\n"
        s += "adfToGeoX:\n"
        for i in range(0, 20):
            s += "  %d: %g\n" % (i, self.adfToGeoX[i])
        s += "adfToGeoY:\n"
        for i in range(0, 20):
            s += "  %d: %g\n" % (i, self.adfToGeoY[i])
        s += "adfFromGeoX:\n"
        for i in range(0, 20):
            s += "  %d: %g\n" % (i, self.adfFromGeoX[i])
        s += "adfFromGeoY:\n"
        for i in range(0, 20):
            s += "  %d: %g\n" % (i, self.adfFromGeoY[i])
        s += "x1_mean: %g\n" % self.x1_mean
        s += "y1_mean: %g\n" % self.y1_mean
        s += "x2_mean: %g\n" % self.x2_mean
        s += "y2_mean: %g\n" % self.y2_mean
        s += "nOrder: %d\n" % self.nOrder
        s += "bReversed: %s\n" % (self.bReversed != 0)
        return s


testPoints = [
    [445975.05, 1226649.62, 11.096094979321196, 122.50530937732474],
    [446278.543, 1226387.363,11.093727776177806, 122.50809226972501],
    [446339.337, 1226594.026, 11.095597664569732, 122.5086458010976],
    [446410.58, 1226693.105, 11.096494759569055, 122.50929663934785]
]


def Main():
    libgdal = ct.CDLL(ctu.find_library("gdal"))
    GDALCreateGCPTransformer = libgdal.GDALCreateGCPTransformer
    GDALCreateGCPTransformer.restype = ct.POINTER(GCPTransformInfo)

    gcps = (Gcp * len(testPoints))()
    for i in range(0, len(testPoints)):
        gcp = gcps[i]
        pt = testPoints[i]
        gcp.pszId = str(i).encode()
        gcp.pszInfo = "".encode()
        gcp.dfGCPPixel = pt[0]
        gcp.dfGCPLine = pt[1]
        gcp.dfGCPX = pt[3]
        gcp.dfGCPY = pt[2]
        gcp.dfGCPZ = 0

    transform = libgdal.GDALCreateGCPTransformer(len(gcps), gcps, 0, 0)
    if transform == 0:
        raise Exception("Transform not solved")
    print(transform.contents)

    libgdal.GDALDestroyGCPTransformer(transform)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Sample output:

```
GDALGCPTransformer
adfToGeoX:
  0: 122.508
  1: 9.15647e-06
  2: -1.51241e-08
  3: 0
  4: 0
  5: 0
  6: 0
  7: 0
  8: 0
  9: 0
  10: 0
  11: 0
  12: 0
  13: 0
  14: 0
  15: 0
  16: 0
  17: 0
  18: 0
  19: 0
adfToGeoY:
  0: 11.0955
  1: 1.49706e-08
  2: 9.0436e-06
  3: 0
  4: 0
  5: 0
  6: 0
  7: 0
  8: 0
  9: 0
  10: 0
  11: 0
  12: 0
  13: 0
  14: 0
  15: 0
  16: 0
  17: 0
  18: 0
  19: 0
adfFromGeoX:
  0: 446251
  1: 109212
  2: 182.642
  3: 0
  4: 0
  5: 0
  6: 0
  7: 0
  8: 0
  9: 0
  10: 0
  11: 0
  12: 0
  13: 0
  14: 0
  15: 0
  16: 0
  17: 0
  18: 0
  19: 0
adfFromGeoY:
  0: 1.22658e+06
  1: -180.788
  2: 110575
  3: 0
  4: 0
  5: 0
  6: 0
  7: 0
  8: 0
  9: 0
  10: 0
  11: 0
  12: 0
  13: 0
  14: 0
  15: 0
  16: 0
  17: 0
  18: 0
  19: 0
x1_mean: 446251
y1_mean: 1.22658e+06
x2_mean: 122.508
y2_mean: 11.0955
nOrder: 1
bReversed: False
```